# How to change HTML style by taking the class name using javascript (no jQuery allowed)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I tried this so far and if I take the element id is working but if I take the class name is not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="p1" class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
<p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

<script>

document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementsByClassName("theClass").style.color = "blue";

document.getElementById("p2").style.fontSize = "larger";
</script>

<p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` give you the list of the nodes. And there is no `style` property on the list. You'll have to  iterate through the list to apply styles.

If there is just on div there you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("theClass")[0].style.color = "red"
```

PS. You should always check your browser's console when something is not working. You'll be seeing an error like `can not ... .style of ...`

```js
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementsByClassName("theClass")[0].style.color = "blue";

document.getElementById("p2").style.fontSize = "larger";

var els = document.getElementsByClassName('theClass1');

for(var i=0; i< els.length; i++){
   els[i].style.color = "green"

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="p1" class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
<p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

<p id="p12" class="theClass1">Hello World 1!</p>
<p id="p14" class="theClass1">Hello World 2!</p>
<p id="p13" class="theClass1">Hello World 3!</p>

<p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, not an element. If you want to apply a style to an element in the collection, select that element first:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("theClass")[0].style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<p id="p1" class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
```

But if you're going to select a single element, it would be much better to use `querySelector`:

```js
document.querySelector('.theClass').style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<p id="p1" class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
```

Even if you did need to apply a style (or do something) to multiple elements with a class name in common, the getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.theClass')
  .forEach(p => p.style.color = "blue");
```

```html
<p class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
<p class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
<p class="theClass">Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: You should specify `.querySelector()` only returns **the first element in DOM to match that selector**.

Comment: I was enthusiastic at first about the simplicity of your forEach script, even upvoted your answer. But it appeared that IE does not support arrow functions. See https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions. That means that we will have to use a function expression, which makes the syntax not much easier than for the `for` loop. And we already know the `for` loop.

Comment: @FrankConijn Any semi-serious project should go through a build process to transform language syntax automatically with Babel. Don't ever gimp yourself by writing in obsolete syntax - that just makes the code more painful to read and write.

Comment: My customers who use IE disagree. And as long as Win7 is still broadly used in the corporate world, they should be considered critical users.

Comment: @FrankConijn I didn't say not to support IE - I said that a build process will take care of those problems automatically, which anything serious should have in place already.

Comment: You're taking this way too far. You're suggesting something that doesn't work in IE. Correct it, supplement it, or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`document.getElementsByClassName("theClass")[0].style.color = "blue";`